# using a friend system in ios parse swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I created a query with subquery

```
var userInitiated = PFQuery(className: "friends")
userInitiated.whereKey("friender", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

var friendInitiated = PFQuery(className: "friends")
friendInitiated.whereKey("friendee", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)

// find friends of user 
let friendQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([userInitiated, friendInitiated])
friendQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) in
    if error == nil {        
        // cleanup 
        self.friendArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        // STEP 2 Hold Recieved Data
        // find objects that you queried for
        for object in objects! {
            self.friendArray.append(object.valueForKey("-----") as! String)
        }
    }
})
```

In the for object in objects part - I want to append the usernames that I got from the query but I only want to add the ones that aren't the current users username, how would I do that?

Comment: I cannot catch what you mean. "I want to append the usernames that I got from the query but I only want to add the ones that aren't the current users username"  If you want to get friends which is not equal to currentUser name, you should use "notEqual".

Comment: I have a class in parse called friends. in the class i have a column called friender and a column called friendee, i want to be able to query to find all the users that the current user is friends with .

Answer (score 0):

A is current User, B is one of A's friends. So what the (friender, friendee) pair in your "friends" class?

1. Both (A,B), (B,A)
2. one of  (A,B) and (B,A)

In first case, you can just query friender equalTo currentUser

In second case, your query seems ok.